# Marmalade Analytics error on startup

Tags: ios, marmalade

(No reponse to this question on Marmalade's own forums, so I'm posting here.)

I'm using Marmalade Analytics on iOS 7, with Marmalade 8.0. I'm using code from the sample to call IwAnalytics::Init. I don't get output from the error or ready callback (which I assume means it's failed to start up so badly that it didn't call them), but I do see the following errors, which look like a problem, when I view the device log:

```
<Warning>:  [0x00000fa0] FILE: open: /var/mobile/Applications/6DE9A5A1-F120-4000-8E01-345009671D0C/Documents/iwanalytics.uid 0X9 0X0
<Warning>:  [0x00000fa0] FILE: s3eFileOpen('iwanalytics.uid', 'r') succeeded, id=1003 p=0x181035c4
<Warning>:  [0x00000fa0] FILE: s3eFileClose h=0x181035c4
<Warning>: ERROR: 4 in device 1
<Warning>:  [0x00000fa0] FILE: s3eFileOpen failed: ('iwanalytics.tc', 'r') (root = )
<Warning>: ERROR: 4 in device 1
<Warning>:  [0x00000fa0] FILE: s3eFileOpen failed: ('iwanalytics.sc', 'r') (root = )
```

Has anyone got Marmalade Analytics working on iOS?

Answer (score 0):

I found that these errors weren't actually a problem. The reason it wasn't working is because I wasn't calling `IwAnalytics::Update()`.